# Change the array/collection order using a REST API

Tags: rest

Do you know any "best practice" to design a REST method to alter the order of a small collection?

I have a collection exposed at "GET /api/v1/items". This endpoint returns a JSON array and every item has a unique id.

I was thinking on create "PATCH /api/v1/items" and send an array of ids with the new order. But I wonder if there is any alternative or design pattern to accomplish this task properly.

Comment: do you mean to change the order by a client? some kind of update operation?

Comment: @dit, that is. I am building a REST API. I need an endpoint to allow a client to change the order of a small collection without "putting" the whole collection again.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Following the REST Uniform Interface constraint, the HTTP `PUT` and `PATCH` methods have to stick to the standard semantics, so you can do that with either one in the following way:

With `PUT`, clients can upload a whole new representation with the order they want. They will request `GET /api/v1/items`, change the order as they need, and submit it back with `PUT /api/v1/items`.

With `PATCH`, clients can send a diff document which performs the order change as they need. You can use a format like [json-patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) and clients perform the change with the `move` operation and array paths.

Be aware that neither of these are design patterns or best practices. They are simply how the `PUT` and `PATCH` methods are supposed to work. Ideally, this should work on any RESTful application implementing the `GET`, `PUT` and `PATCH` methods correctly for the resource at that URI, and that's the beauty of REST. If you do it the right way, you only have to do it once and clients can generalize for everyone. For instance, a client can choose to do it the `PUT` way with small collections, and the `PATCH` way for larger ones.

Both your idea to use `PATCH` with an id array, and the answerfrom @dit suggesting to do it with `PUT` aren't really RESTful because they are breaking up with the standard semantics: yours for not using a delta format, his for doing partial updates with `PUT`. However, both those options can be RESTful if done with `POST`. `POST` is the method to go for any action that isn't standardized by the HTTP protocol, so you can do anything you want with it, but you have to document how exactly to do it.

So, it's up to you. If you are concerned at all with being RESTful and your application has long term goals -- I'm talking years or even decades -- I'd say to go for a uniform implementation of the `PUT` and `PATCH` methods as suggested first. If you prefer a simple approach, use yours or dit's idea with `POST`.

Comment: I am thinking also adding a priority attribute and let the client do the sorting and to alter the order "PATCH /items/:id" with priority value.

Comment: If the array order is stable, I don't think that's needed, but if it makes it clearer for you, go for it.

Answer (score 7):

ok, I had a similar problem and will try to explain how I solved it.

my bike tour has about 5 stations. Every station has an unique ID and order number:

```
stations": [

    {
        "uid": 1,
        "order": 1
    },
    {
        "uid": 2,
        "order": 2
    },
    {
        "uid": 3,
        "order": 3
    },
    {
        "uid": 4,
        "order": 4
    },
    {
        "uid": 5,
        "order": 5
    }

]
```

**Every time** if the order of single item was changed (drag and drop) i send REST request to my webservice.

Suppose we want to move the station *uid=3* one position down. Station with *uid=3* goes down and station with *uid=4* goes up. So my *PUT* request looks like this:

```
...myapplication.com/api/changeorder?station=3&direction=down
```

Now, on the server side I just have to find items affected by this move down action and update their order in my database. My REST webservice sends `OK` if update was successful.

In my case it was not necessary to send the new sorted list, cause my UI was always changed by drag and drop action.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not going to promote changes in the current API, I have used PUT method.
I was implementing a reordering of entities called "Slider". dotnet core

```
public class SliderMoveDto
{
    public MoveDirection MoveDirection { get; set; }

    public int CurrentSequence { get; set; }
}

public enum MoveDirection
{
    Down = 0,
    Up = 1
}
```

Implementation:

```
    public async Task UpdateAsync(SliderMoveDto sliderMoveDto, int sliderId)
    {
        var allSliders = (await _sliderRepository.GetAsync(null, col => col.OrderBy(s => s.Sequence))).ToList<Slider>();
        int currentIndexOfSliderInList = allSliders.FindIndex(s => s.Sequence == sliderMoveDto.CurrentSequence);
        int indexToSwap = sliderMoveDto.MoveDirection == MoveDirection.Up
            ? currentIndexOfSliderInList-1
            : currentIndexOfSliderInList+1;

        SwapItems<Slider>(allSliders, currentIndexOfSliderInList, indexToSwap);

        await RecalculateOrderOfSliders(allSliders);
    }
```

Auxiliary methods:

```
       public static void SwapItems<T>(IList<T> list, int indexA, int indexB)
    {
        T tmp = list[indexA];
        list[indexA] = list[indexB];
        list[indexB] = tmp;
    }

    private async Task RecalculateOrderOfSliders(List<Slider> allSliders)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < allSliders.Count; index++)
        {
            int idOfSlider = allSliders[index].Id;
            var sliderToUpdate = await _sliderRepository.GetByIdAsync(idOfSlider);
            sliderToUpdate.Sequence = index + 1;
            _sliderRepository.Update(sliderToUpdate);
        }

        await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
    }
```